# C: Palindrome: Different strlen-values

Tags: c, string, palindrome, strcmp, reversing

I'm making a function which reverses a string and checks if the string is a palindrome or not. When I test the function with a obvious palindrome like "abba", the function says it's not a palindrome. Also the forward string and the reversed string also differ in string length!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char forward [] = "abba"; //The string to be reversed

int size = (sizeof(forward)/sizeof(forward[0]) - 1);
int j = 0;
char reverse [10];

void reverser(char forward []) {

    printf("%s", "String forward: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Function for printing out the forward string.
        printf("%c", forward[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("%s", "String reversed: ");

    for (int i = size, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) { //Function for reversing the string and printing it.
        reverse[j] = forward[i];
        printf("%c", reverse[j]);       
    }

    printf("\n");

    if (strcmp(forward, reverse) != 0) { //Using strcmp to check if the forward and reversed string are the same. 
        printf("Not a palindrome!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("A palindrome!\n");
    }

    printf("Forward string length: %d\n",strlen(forward));
    printf("Reversed string length: %d\n",strlen(reverse));
} 

int main () {
    reverser(forward);      
}
```

**Output:**
String forward: abba
String reversed: abba
Not a palindrome!
Forward string length: 9
Reversed string length: 0

Comment: Please indent your code correctly,  I cannot understand it.

Comment: `int i = size` --> `int i = size-1`

Comment: What is this? Why not strlen() here? int size = (sizeof(forward)/sizeof(forward[0]) - 1);

Comment: @YurySchkatula: because `size` is a global variable :(.  The real question is *Why is `size` a global variable?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for (int i = size, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) { //Function for reversing the string and printing it.
    reverse[j] = forward[i];
    printf("%c", reverse[j]);       
    }
```

forward[i] is the terminating zero of the string when the initial value of variable `i` is equal to `size`

Try the following loop implementation

```
for ( int i = size, j = 0; i != 0; ++j) { //Function for reversing the string and printing it.
    reverse[j] = forward[--i];
    printf("%c", reverse[j]);       
    }
```

Also take into account that for variables that will store values returned by the operator `sizeof` or by the function `strlen` it is better to use type `size_t`.

So in these statements

```
printf("Forward string length: %d\n",strlen(forward));
printf("Reversed string length: %d\n",strlen(reverse));
```

use format specifier `%zu` instead of `%d`

For example

```
printf("Forward string length: %zu\n",strlen(forward));
printf("Reversed string length: %zu\n",strlen(reverse));
```

Some answerers here said that you have to zero-terminate the string `reverse`. However it is already zero-terminated because it is declared outside any function and as result has the static storage duration and as such it is zero-initialized by default.

Comment: Also note that `reverse` is not null terminated.

Comment: @chqrlie Why do you have decided so?

Comment: Because even if it is not strictly necessary thanks to `reverse` being a global variable and the operation happening only once, I believe the OP is not aware that his code cannot be used in a more general manner.

Comment: @chqrlie You said that I should note that reverse is not null terminated.However it is a wrong statement.:)

Comment: OK. let's put it this way: it would be good advice for the OP remind him to null terminate `reverse` so the function works in the general case.  Obviously the use of global variable `size` is not good practice either, the arbitrary size of 10 bytes is questionable too...

Answer (score 0):

I think the first char of "reversed" is '\0'.

Replace this line `int size = (sizeof(forward)/sizeof(forward[0]) - 1);` by `int size = strlen(forward)`.

Moreover :

`printf("%s", "String forward: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Function for printing out the forward string.
    printf("%c", forward[i]);
 }`

can be replaced by `printf("String forward : %s\n", forward);`

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the null character in the first index when reversing (`reverse[0]`). That's why every fails.

```
for (int i = size, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {         
    reverse[j] = forward[i];
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = size - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
    reverse[j] = forward[i];
}
reverse[size] = '\0';
```

`sizeof(forward)/sizeof(forward[0])` is 5 which means `size = 4`.

```
forward[0] = 'a'
forward[1] = 'b'
forward[2] = 'b'
forward[3] = 'a'
forward[4] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reversing code is off by one on one of the indices, `i` should run from `size-1` to `0` inclusive:

```
// Function for reversing the string.
for (int i = size, j = 0; i > 0;) {
    reverse[j++] = forward[--i];
}
reverse[size] = '\0';
```

To avoid updating 2 different indices, you can simplify this loop:

```
// Function for reversing the string.
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    reverse[i] = forward[size - 1 - i];
}
reverse[size] = '\0';
```

There are many other issues in your code:

- `forward` and `size` are global variables, but you also name the argument in function `reverser` the same way and use the global `size` there, which may be inappropriate if called with a different argument.  `size` and even worse `j` should not be global variables (!)
- function name `reverser` is inconsistent with what the function does: printing its argument.
- you can print the argument string directly with a `%s` printf format.  No need for a loop.
- `%d` is not the correct format for `strlen()` return value.  Either cast as `(int)strlen(forward)` or use `%zu`.

Comment: You should make your code easier to understand by removing the `j++` and `--i` from those brackets and place them in their proper place in the for-loop

Comment: @Smac89: I put them there on purpose actually.  Downward loops should not use `>= 0` because this test is inappropriate for unsigned variables.  Pre-decrementing the index upon use or postdecrementing it in the test expression is idiomatic, albeit confusing for beginners.  The proposed alternative is simpler and less error prone.